# Is there any escape sequence in command prompt, just like the c language has?

Tags: terminal, directory, whitespace, command-prompt, backslash

I need to enter into a directory which has spaces in its name, like:

> ".\Desktop\Express\fab Class\node_modules".

So, I need to escape the spaces in the name.

I have tried backslash but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which shell, terminal and OS do you use? In bash on Ubuntu backslash works just fine

Comment: windows 10 command prompt, not shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using double quotes should work. Also, you can use **TAB** key while typing the directory name; it will automatically show you the specified directory name in quotes.

While you are typing the directory path: "**.\Desktop\Express\fab**  press **Tab** key, after that it will automatically convert the Path to the correct directory name.

Comment: Bonus with this: you don't need to add the opening double-quote before hitting tab, the console will add it for you if it's needed.

Comment: Agree IMSop, Thanks for adding that

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes to escape paths with spaces in Windows 10:

[image]

Backslash works in Linux.